# Worker don't receive MessageChannel object in getSharedProperty()

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, worker

I'm creating a AIR application, with the AIR 23 SDK, and need use the `Worker` object. With [this adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) I made a simple example to understand it. The code is below:

```
if(Worker.current.isPrimordial) {

    var worker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(this.loaderInfo.bytes);

    var mainToWorker:MessageChannel = Worker.current.createMessageChannel(worker);
    var workerToMain:MessageChannel = worker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);

    worker.setSharedProperty("mtw", mainToWorker);
    worker.setSharedProperty("wtm", workerToMain);

    worker.start();

    trace("[MAIN] Start worker.");
    trace("[MAIN] Property one: "+worker.getSharedProperty("mtw"));
    trace("[MAIN] Property two: "+worker.getSharedProperty("wtm"));

}
else {

    trace("[WORKER] Status: "+Worker.current.state);

    var mtw = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("mtw");
    var wtm = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("wtm");

    trace("[WORKER] Property one: "+mtw);
    trace("[WORKER] Property two: "+wtm);

}
```

But the output traces are:

```
[MAIN] Start worker.
[MAIN] Property one: [object MessageChannel]
[MAIN] Property two: [object MessageChannel]
[WORKER] Status: running
[WORKER] Property one: undefined
[WORKER] Property two: undefined
```

When I change the AIR SDK to the 3.4, it works! The traces changes to: `[WORKER] Property one: [object MessageChannel]` and `[WORKER] Property two: [object MessageChannel]`.

Is it a bug? Can someone help me?

Comment: Your code works for me in Flash builder.  I don't have Flash CS6, though, so I can't check it there.

Comment: I tested in _MAC OSX - Animate CC_ and _Windows 10 Flash CS6_, the same error occurs